# How to pass method to block in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

How to pass `plus` into `calculate` method?

```
def calculate(&block : (Float64, Float64) -> Float64)
  block.call(1.1, 2.2)
end

def plus(a, b)
  a + b
end

calculate{|a, b| plus a, b}
```

This won't work

```
calculate ->plus
calculate &plus
```

P.S.

Another question, how to make it to work for all numbers? Not just `Float64`. This code won't compile and complain about requiring more specific type than `Number`

```
def calculate(&block : (Number, Number) -> Number)
  block.call(1, 2)
end
```

Ideally it would be nice to make it generalised so that `typeof(block.call(1, 2)) => Int32` and `typeof(block.call(1.1, 2.2)) => Float64`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to pass plus into calculate method?

You're looking for

```
calculate(&->plus(Float64, Float64))
```

Where `->plus(Float64, Float64)` returns a `Proc`. Mind that you *have* to specify the type of the arguments - see the section [From methods](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/literals/proc.html) in the reference manual.

> how to make it to work for all numbers?

I'd look into `forall` - see the section on [Free variables](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/type_restrictions.html) in the reference manual.

Answer (score 2):

A generalized solution could work with free variables, but there's a catch because free variables can't be derived from block arguments:

```
def calculate(&block : (T, T) -> T) forall T # Error: undefined constant T
```

This is because block arguments can't be overloaded since they can simply be captured blocks without type restrictions.

There are two options to make this work:

1. You can pass the type for `T` explicitly as an argument. This is a bit more verbose but works with a captured block argument.

```
def plus(a, b)
  a + b
end

def calculate(t : T.class, &block : (T, T) -> T) forall T
  block.call(1.1, 2.2)
end

calculate(Float64, &->plus(Float64, Float64))
```

2. You can change the captured block argument to a normal argument receiving a `Proc`:

```
def plus(a, b)
  a + b
end

def calculate(block : (T, T) -> T) forall T
  block.call(1.1, 2.2)
end

calculate(->plus(Float64, Float64))
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I want a normal argument, I added `&` to `Proc` because I thought it's the way it's supposed to be :).